# Change TabLayout tabs placement

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am using `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager` in order to display my tabs names like below.

[image]

But as you can see my title is covering my tabs. I wish to have my tabs close to the top of my screen like below.

[image]

Here is my `view_pager.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="stellar.kade_c.com.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Please refer  android hive tutorial  http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `app:tabMode="fixed"` to `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

**FIXED**

> Fixed tabs display all tabs concurrently and are best used with
>   content that benefits from quick pivots between tabs. The maximum
>   number of tabs is limited by the view’s width. Fixed tabs have equal
>   width, based on the widest tab label.

**SCROLLABLE**

> Scrollable tabs display a subset of tabs at any given moment, and can
>   contain longer tablabels and a larger number of tabs. They are best
>   used for browsing contexts in touch interfaces when users don’t need
>   to directly compare the tab labels.

Comment: That simply seems to move them both to the left without changing their distance to the top of the screen.

Comment: @ChristopherK. so you always want your tab title contains 2 line right?

Comment: I wish to have them centered and as close to the top of the screen as possible

Comment: @ChristopherK. currently the height of your Tab is `wrap_content`, and it have displayed correct. if you want your Tab close to top you can make the Tab height shorter by change the height of your Tab to a specific height (60dp or ...

Comment: if you want your tab more close to top, you can change your tab title to 1 line, and `use app:tabMode="scrollable"`